# Quick loading splash screen after re-accessing the app in Android Kotlin

Tags: java, android, android-studio, kotlin, splash-screen

I have a splash screen that starts and lasts for 5 seconds, then disappears and continues or is replaced with MainActivity, but I want when I press the back button and reopen the application, the splash screen will load faster than at first open (<5s), so how to do it.

This my code:

```
class SplashActivity : BaseActivity() {

    companion object{
        private const val PREFS:String = "prefs"
        private const val FIRST_RUN:String = "first_run"
        private const val SPLASH_DELAY: Long = 5000
    }


    private var mDelayHandler: Handler? = null

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_splash)

        mDelayHandler = Handler()
        mDelayHandler!!.postDelayed(mRunnable, SPLASH_DELAY)

        var animation: Animation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this,R.anim.splash_animation)
        logo.startAnimation(animation)
    }

    private val mRunnable = Runnable {
        Thread(Runnable {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(100)
            } catch (e: InterruptedException) {
                e.printStackTrace()
            }
            startActivity()

        }).start()
    }

    private fun startActivity() {
        val settings = getSharedPreferences(PREFS, 0)
        val firstRun = settings.getBoolean(FIRST_RUN, false)
        var intent = if (!firstRun) {
            val editor = settings.edit()
            editor.putBoolean(FIRST_RUN, true)
            editor.commit()
            Intent(this, OnBoardingActivity::class.java)

        } else {
            Intent(this, MainActivity::class.java)
        }

        intent.flags = Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP
        startActivity(intent)
        this.finish()

        mDelayHandler!!.removeCallbacks(mRunnable)

    }

    override fun onDestroy() {
        mDelayHandler?.removeCallbacks(mRunnable)
        super.onDestroy()
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a static variable, try this

```
companion object{
    private var SPLASH_DELAY: Long = 5000
}
```

```
mDelayHandler!!.postDelayed(mRunnable, SPLASH_DELAY)
SPLASH_DELAY = 1000
```

Comment: I think this is not a good solution, because if you do it your way, the variable SPLASH_DELAY = 1000 for the first run.

Comment: No you call postDelayed before you set SPLAH_DELAY to 1000

Answer (score 0):

You may need to check the lifecycle of SplashActivity before calling startActivity().
Also, using postDelayed() is better than Thread.sleep()